# HOWTO know whether an incoming request in ASP.NET MVC is triggered by an user interaction(user logged in) or by the asp.net MVC app itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I have implemented my custom Controller which inherits from System.Web.Mvc.Controller and overrides some methods like BeginExecute and OnActionExecuting (below their signature):

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
```

Then all my MVC controllers inherit from my custom controller.

I have noticed that when app is idle (no users interacting/working with it), the BeginExecute event is triggerd several times for each minute is elapsed.

So I would like to differenciate whether the incoming request through BeginExecute corresponds to either an user interaction with the application (user logged in) or to the application itself when it is idle (no user interaction exists, I mean, no user logged in). is there any way to do it?

Comment: how can an idle application fire unless there is any outside event like jobs etc.?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Yes, I agree with you. I do not understand why idle app is firing BeginExecute event when no user is interacting with it. I have observed the call stack and it says external code and then next call is BeginExecute. How can I know what is causing BeginExecute event to fire? Is there any way to know who is the external code causing it? I log to database each time this event is fired, and I have observed that if I stop application pool for this site, then it stops writting logs to database, so the culprit is the asp.net mvc app itself, no outside events like jobs, etc is firing it

Comment: Can you log the request header at global.asax biginrequest event and analyze?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I can try it. Could you post a code snippet on how to do that? Anyway, can I get the request header from Session_Start in global.asax instead? If so how.

Comment: Here you go: 

`protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;
        }`

you can log browser details etc.